# Qt: Safe Fonts for Cross Platform Desktop App

Tags: qt

Just a thought: is there any resource somewhere with a list "safe-fonts" for a cross platform desktop Qt app that needs to run on windows, Mac and Linux (Ubuntu 10.* for instance).

and while we're on the subject, is there any way to "package" a font with the executable as part of the resources and have it run seamlessly in all three platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never tried it but I think you can use [addApplicationFont](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont) to load a font from a file. The file can be part of your app's resource.

Comment: I can confirm that worked for me under Linux with a TTF font and you should be able to bundle it up as a resource.

Comment: That's cool. If Linux can do it, i have no doubts OSX will too. After all, it processed TTF fonts naturally.

Comment: One thing that to watch for is referencing the font by name when you go to use it (say in a QFont constructor), the name (family) will likely not be the font's filename exactly. I'm not sure of the correct way to determine this, I succeeded by guessing with a font I was using :)